# "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable - printing an output of a step

Tags: ansible, jinja2

So I have a playbook which I use to terminate users:

```
---
- name: "Playbook: Terminate user"
    hosts: localhost
    gather_facts: True

    roles:
    - { role: common, tags: ['always'] }
    - { role: ad_termination, tags: ['ad_termination', 'never'] }

- name: "Playbook: Terminate storage"
    hosts: storage
    gather_facts: False
    roles:
    - { role: storage_termination, tags: ['storage_termination', 'always'] }

- name: "Playbook: User environment"
    hosts: localhost
    gather_facts: False

    roles:
    - { role: common,
        tags: ['always'],
        }

    - { role: send_summary_email,
        tags: ['send_summary_email', 'always']
        }
```

I call it using the following command:

`ansible-playbook userOperations/userTerminationPB.yml -t ad_termination -e "username=user"`. It then goes over each playbook (3 in total).

All is fine with the first 2 playbooks (terminate user and terminate storage). I'm having issues passing a variable from the second playbook (`terminate storage`).

As you can see, the `hosts` configured for the storage playbook is called `storage`. It holds a few servers.

This is the playbook itself:

```
- name: Logical block of home-storage tasks
  block:
  - name: Check if home folder exists
    stat:
      path: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].fspath }}/{{ username }}"
    register: home_dir_details

  - name: Move user home folder to terminated home folder
    command: mv {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].fspath }}/{{ username }} "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].fspath }}/terminated/{{ username }}"
    when: home_dir_details.stat.exists
    register: storage_moved

  - name: Printing and debugging
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "{{ storage_moved }}"
  when: 
    - hostvars[inventory_hostname].fsname is search("home")
```

I'm trying to summarize everything in an email. My email is a jinja2 template that I edit using those passed variables.

My problem is when I use `{{ storage_moved }}` in my Jinja2 template (3rd playbook that sends the email), it's not recognized as a variable.

I'm not sure what to change in order for it to be recognized. I simply use `{{ storage_moved }}` in my template but it doesn't work.

It should print the following:

```
ok: [storage.server.com] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": [
            "mv",
            "/path/user",
            "/path/terminated/user"
        ],
        "delta": "0:00:00.006022",
        "end": "2021-10-19 16:13:03.468398",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2021-10-19 16:13:03.462376",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "",
        "stdout_lines": []
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Currently I'm getting:

`"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'storage_moved' is undefined`

**Edit:**

I was able to access all the info in `storage_moved` by using the following loop in my jinja2 tempalte:

```
{% for host in groups['storage'] %}
{{ hostvars[host]['storage_moved'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: if your register var doenst exist, the reason the task does nothing... are you sure the task 'Move user home folder to terminated home folder' is not skipped?

Comment: @Frenchy yes. I can see the output in the playbook itself. I get a dict `msg` that has: `changed, cmd(the command itself), delta, end, failed, rc, start, stderr, stdout`, etc.

Comment: so if i understand, you want to access a variable created in one playbook, from another playbook?

Comment: I guess that would be right. It's worth mentioning that I'm a newbie with Ansible in general. Also, I mentioned that my lack of access to that variable probably comes from the fact that my main playbook runs the last step in `hosts: localhost`. So it might be related to that but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: yes you have trapped the problem, different hosts...sowhy dont create a dummy_host like in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
{% for host in groups['storage'] %}
<li>{{ hostvars[host]['storage_moved']['cmd'] | default('') }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

The fix was adding `| default('') }}` to my search, because during the loop the `cmd` variable might not always be present.

Answer (score 1):

not tested, but you could add dummy host with var in the playbook where you defined your storage

```
   - name: Register dummy host with variable
     add_host:
       name: "DUMMY_HOST"
       STORAGE_NEW:  "{{ storage_moved }}"   #storage_moved.stdout
```

and in the other playbook you echo the variable:

```
  tasks:
   - name: Echo the output - storage_new var
     shell: cat {{ hostvars['DUMMY_HOST']['STORAGE_NEW'] }} |tail -1
     register: STORAGE_RESULT
```

Comment: Thanks, it somewhat worked but I ended up almost figuring it out. I edited my original post to show the loop I used to access the variables inside of `storage_moved`.