# Ansible share variable across plays that use different inventories

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I have two playbooks : `create_infrastructure.yml` and `bootstrap_cluster.yml`. The first playbook uses a static inventory that only defines the `infrastructure` group with one member : `127.0.0.1`. This is used to build the infrastructure on which to deploy a kubernetes cluster.
The second playbook uses a dynamic inventory, `hcloud.yml`, and is responsible for bootstrapping a kubernetes cluster.
One of the roles executed in `bootstrap_cluster.yml` needs access to the control plane loadbalancer's IP address which is something known by the `create_infrastructure.yml` playbook.
I've tried using both the `register` option and the `set_fact` module but couln't seem to make it work. Indeed trying to access `hostvars['infrastructure']['control_plane_ip']` from `bootstrap_cluster.yml` doesn't make much sense as the `infrastructure` group is not even defined in the dynamic inventory used by the playbook.
Any idea on how I might dynamically share a variable between playbook that targets different hosts?

Comment: do you launch both playbooks?

Answer (score 1):

To disseminate a variable across all hosts within an Ansible play, you can define it using the set_fact module combined with the run_once: true directive. Setting run_once to true ensures that the variable is established a single time and made available to every host in the play.

Below is a sample playbook for illustration:

```
- hosts: host1, host2
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Set a variable to be shared among all hosts
      set_fact:
        hello: world
      run_once: true

    - name: Display the variable for each host
      debug:
        msg: "{{ hello }}"
```

Executing this playbook results in the output "world" for both "host1" and "host2", although the variable hello is only assigned once. This method is particularly effective when working with a substantial number of hosts or when it's necessary to make a single API request, instead of one per host, while still propagating the value to all hosts.

Answer (score 0):

If you launch playbooks in the same call, you can test my solution with a dummy host:

[Pass Var between different hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69643187/msg-the-task-includes-an-option-with-an-undefined-variable-printing-an-out?noredirect=1#comment123101498_69643187)

```
# Combine multiple playbooks in the same call combine.yml for example:
  - import_playbook: play1.yml
  - import_playbook: play2.yml
```

If your playbooks are  launched in two separate calls, the only solution is to create a file shared between the 2 playbooks.

Comment: Unfortunately I run the playbook separately (would it even be possible to use different inventories with a single call?) but I can't really use a shared variable file since the IP address is "randomly" picked by the cloud-provider. I guess I could have one playbook create a file with the IP address that subsequent playbook use but seems like a convoluted solution. Weird, I thought such use case are quite frequent and ansible provided a built-in solution to share variables across playbooks/inventories.  Thanks a lot for your answer tho!

Comment: yes you could launch 2 playbook in same file with inventory different